# What is the correct place to insert 'placeholder' in ChoiceType?

Tags: symfony, bootstrap-4, twig, symfony-forms

I am working with Symfony 5.2 with Bootstrap 4, and I am designing a form that contains a ChoiceType field. I need a placeholder to appear such as "Select an option". I have tried different options and none of them work. My file ComisionNewFormType.php:

```
  ->add('turno', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Turno:',
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => '-Seleccione un turno',
    ],
    'choices' => [
    'Mañana' => 'Mañana' ,
    'Tarde' => 'Tarde',
    'Noche' => 'Noche' ,
    'Desconocido' =>'Desconocido' ,
     ],      
])
```

My Twig template is:

```
 <div class="col">
    Intensidad:<font color="red"> {{ form_errors(form.turno)}}</font>
    {{ form_widget(form.turno, {'attr': {'placeholder': '-Seleccione un turno'}}) }}  
 </div>
```

The result, however, looks like this, without the "placeholder":

[image]

The source code in Firefox looks like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-2"> 
        Turno:
<select id="comision_new_form_turno" name="comision_new_form[turno]" class="form-control form-control">
<option value="Mañana">Mañana</option>
<option value="Tarde">Tarde</option>
<option value="Noche">Noche</option>
<option value="Desconocido">Desconocido</option>
</select>            
</div>
```

The placeholder does not appear.

How should I make the placeholder visible in the form in the mentioned field?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the doc says, you have to use the placeholder from the `ChoiceType` options (https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#placeholder)

```
->add('turno', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Turno:',
    'placeholder' => '-Seleccione un turno',
    'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control',
     ],
    'choices' => [
    'Mañana' => 'Mañana' ,
    'Tarde' => 'Tarde',
    'Noche' => 'Noche' ,
    'Desconocido' =>'Desconocido' ,
     ],      
])
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much for pointing out the error. I delete in ForMType:  'attr' => [
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'placeholder' => '-Seleccione un turno',
    ], and put the the line: 'placeholder' => '-Seleccione un turno', and It works.

Answer (score 0):

Applying the solution proposed by "jona303" the complete code would look like this:
The file ComisionNewFormType.php:

```
 ->add('turno', ChoiceType::class, [
    'label' => 'Turno:',
    'placeholder' => '-Seleccione',      
    'choices' => [
    'Mañana' => 'Mañana' ,
    'Tarde' => 'Tarde',
    'Noche' => 'Noche' ,
    'Desconocido' =>'Desconocido' ,
     ],      
])
```

Twig template is:

```
<div class="col-sm-2"> 
    Turno:<font color="red"> {{ form_errors(form.turno)}}</font>
           {{ form_widget(form.turno) }}            
 </div>
```

The result would look like this:

[image]